# How to make the status bar translucent when using react-navigation on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using latest react-native(0.45.1) and react-navigation(1.0.0-beta.11).
Because using react-navigation, i can't use ReactNative.StatusBar, so I don't know how to make the status bar translucent.
Maybe effective both on Android and iOS, THX!

Comment: Looks to be an [open issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/11) with different approaches on how to best handle this. Perhaps take a look at the Github comments and see if any of the suggestions are appropriate for you.

Comment: THX, I has committed an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StatusBar
   translucent
   backgroundColor="#5E8D48"
   barStyle="light-content"
/>
```